# where is logind.conf in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I have heard that the logind.conf file should be in /etc/systemd/logind.conf. however, it doesn't appear there, and a file search reveals that it isn't ANYWHERE.

So what file replaces logind.conf, or where can I find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04, `logind.conf` is provided by the package `systemd-services`, but this package does not exist in 12.04. I suppose that the source where you read about it was about 14.04, not 12.04.

Comment: I get the notice E: unable to locate package systemd-services

Comment: Sorry, `systemd-services` does not exist in 12.04, I will edit my answer.

Comment: this is true, but the question still remains, how do i modify these buttons in 12.04?

Comment: What "buttons"?

Comment: the reason I want to edit this file is to disable the power button. for some reason my computer will randomly believe the power button is pressed, and pop up the dialogue window. The other problem is that sometimes the power button will be HELD DOWN, shutting down the computer completely too, so really, this would still only solve half the problem

Comment: Then you need to post a question about that. ;)

Comment: yeah, sorry, I'll edit my original question